# Calendar control in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, calendar

I'm having an doubt about silverlight calendar control.,
I'm running my silverlight calendar control application in my local pc and it highlights the current date of my pc.If suppose i host my application to a server.,In this condition, whether the calendar control highlights, the date from the server or the date from the local pc where the application is accessed.

Thanks.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date of the local client will be shown.